# SAS Enterprise Guide: Report Showing Percentage Difference Between Columns

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have designed the following report using the List Data task in SAS EG.

- 1st Column: List of Products
- 2nd Column: Sum of Q1 Sales
- 3rd Column: Sum of Q2 Sales
- 4th Column: Percentage Difference between Q1 and Q2

The issue with my design is that when it comes to the totals row, it shows the sum of 4th column. I would like it to calculate the percentage difference between the total of Column 3 and 2.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that via the List Data task.  You can't even really modify the code from that task without effectively writing it from scratch, because that task uses `PROC PRINT`, which won't do the math for you (it will subtotal/total but it won't create a new variable, which is basically what you want).
You'd pretty much want to write this by hand, as far as I know - I don't see an easy way to do this from any of the tasks directly. Are you comfortable with SAS programming?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Joe. I figured as much. I was wondering whether there was another inbuilt task I could use, but you also answered that. As far as SAS programming, it's something I'm currently working on learning.

Comment: I certainly don't know the tasks in great detail, so it's possible I'm wrong.  It's probably worth posting on communities.sas.com if you don't get an answer here - there are more EG users over there, plus the developers, who would give you a good answer.

Comment: The answer partly depends on how your data appears, so what does it look like. You can use the Query Tool to get most of the way there and then use the list report to display the output. Programming is always faster though.

Comment: Right - you can use query to create the query that does what you want, except I think it's probably fairly hard to create totals in query tool, isn't it?

Comment: Depends on data structure. Can either calculate diff in one and then use proc report/tabulate wizard to create table or manually create total and append.  Not as efficient as programming but stays within the 'GUI' environment.

Comment: @JayeshMenon consider posting this on communities.sas.com in the EG forum where some of the EG developers can comment.

Answer (score 0):

**This should do the trick:** 
Using summary tables, calculating the percentage of the variable. Further you have to export the results into a data set.

Then use the query builder to calculate the `variable/100` for a representation between 0-1. This is done via the the advanced expression feature.